# Publish apk to remote maven repo

Tags: android, maven

How to publish my android studio project's apk to a remote maven repo? Please let know if you have any idea, I tried but didn't get any document for publishing projects made in android studio. Any links to such documents would be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bintray plugin. First, create your account in [Bintray](http://www.bintray.com/). Then, configure your build.gradle this way:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    }
}

bintray {
    user = yourBintrayUser
    key = yourBintrayKey
    filesSpec {
        from 'build/outputs/apk/'
        into 'com/yourcompany/project/1.0.0'
    }
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'your-project-name'
        vcsUrl = 'yourVcsUrl'
        version {
            name = '1.0.0'
            desc = 'Your Project v.1.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you will have a Gradle task named 'uploadBintray' and when you execute it, it will create a repository in your Bintray account and will upload all files inside `build/outputs/apk` in it.

**EDIT**

If you have a own downloads server, and you don't want deploy the apk in Bintray servers, you can use my gradle plugin [GRelease](https://github.com/bigdestroyer/grelease).

Comment: I went through Bintray, it seems they host the apk in their own server. I already have a server for hosting my apk. I am looking for a way to put in my apk into it.